# Twitter4J force closes for searching something in twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to test `Twitter4j` to display some tweets using the search. At the moment, It should not print anything on the screen, just a `system.out.printIn` to my eclipse. But it force closes.

This is my `mainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
        twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
        QueryResult result = null;
        try {
            result = twitter.search(query);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

and I used also `twitter4j.properties`

```
debug=true
oauth.consumerKey=xxxxxxxxx
oauth.consumerSecret=bxxxxxxxxxxx
oauth.accessToken=xxxxxxxxxxx
oauth.accessTokenSecret=xxxxxxx
```

the problem is, once I open the app it foce closes. The `logcat`:

```
11-09 00:15:07.124: E/AndroidRuntime(32369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 00:15:07.124: E/AndroidRuntime(32369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxxxxx/MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for the detail.
11-09 00:15:07.124: E/AndroidRuntime(32369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
```

Comment: Did you even read the LogCat? It tells you all you need to know. `Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for the detail.`

Comment: yes but I have the authentication credetials, see my twitter4j.properties and configbuilder

Comment: did you try putting the credentials statically in the your java method and then checking??